# Access violation. C++ polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm kinda starting to learn polymorphism in C++. This code gives me "access violation reading location 0xFDFDFD00". Visual Studio 2012 Pro. Debugger says, that "__vfptr" of "i" is "0xfdfdfd00 {???}".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Enemy {
public:
    virtual void loop() = 0;
};

class EnemyA{
public:
    void loop() {
        cout << "Pew-pew\n";
    }
};
class EnemyB {
public:
    void loop() {
        cout << "Pow-pow\n";
    }
};
class EnemyC {
public:
    void loop() {
        cout << "KABOOM\n";
    }
};

vector <Enemy*> enemies;

int main() {
    enemies.push_back((Enemy*) new EnemyA());
    enemies.push_back((Enemy*) new EnemyB());
    enemies.push_back((Enemy*) new EnemyC());

    for (Enemy* i : enemies) {
        i->loop();
    }
}
```

Comment: You've never actually inherited from Enemy class. Write `class EnemyA: Enemy` instead of just `class EnemyA`

Comment: @Blablablaster You should post that as an answer, it's correct.

Comment: *facepalm* Just forgot about it

Comment: You should really turn up compiler warnings, and *listen* to them.

Comment: I have standard warnings level (/W3), and it stays quiet about that

Comment: Turn up the warning level. VS is incredibly lax where it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to actually inherit from the `Enemy` class:

```
class Derivet : public Base {};
```

Answer (score 1):

To inherit `EnemyA` from `Enemy`, you need to do:

```
class EnemyA : public Enemy {
  // ...
}
```

And likewise for `EnemyB` and `EnemyC`.

Otherwise you are casting an `EnemyA*` to an `Enemy*`, where `EnemyA` and `Enemy` are completely unrelated classes - this is not safe. This would have been caught for you if you hadn't put the `(Enemy*)` cast in there. This is performing a `reinterpret_cast`, which just blindly lets you convert between unrelated pointers.

If you had tried to simply not cast at all, you would have gotten an error like this:

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
    enemies.push_back(new EnemyA());
    ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

Since the cast from derived pointer to base pointer is an implicit conversion, this should have worked, so you can tell that you haven't actually derived `EnemyA` from `Enemy`.

The lesson is to not just stick a C-style cast in there to try and make your code work.

Answer (score 1):

You never actually inherited `Enemy`. That's why you need to cast all your sub-enemies.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Enemy {
public:
    virtual void loop() = 0;
};

class EnemyA : public Enemy {
public:
    virtual void loop() {
        cout << "Pew-pew\n";
    }
};
class EnemyB : public Enemy {
public:
    virtual void loop() {
        cout << "Pow-pow\n";
    }
};
class EnemyC : public Enemy  {
public:
    virtual void loop() {
        cout << "KABOOM\n";
    }
};

vector <Enemy*> enemies;

int main() {
    enemies.push_back(new EnemyA());
    enemies.push_back(new EnemyB());
    enemies.push_back(new EnemyC());

    for (Enemy* i : enemies) {
        i->loop();
    }
}
```

Please note that you still have a memory leak. You never deleted those instances created with `new`. Right here, it does not matter because ending the process will free all memory on most systems, when you writer larger programs you need to be aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

None of your classes `EnemyA`,  `EnemyB` or `EnemyC` is inherited from `Enemy`.

These three classes should look like,

```
class EnemyA : public Enemy{
public:
    void loop() {
        cout << "Pew-pew\n";
    }
};
class EnemyB : public Enemy {
public:
    void loop() {
        cout << "Pow-pow\n";
    }
};
class EnemyC : public Enemy {
public:
    void loop() {
        cout << "KABOOM\n";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your `class EnemyA` etc. to inherit from `class Enemy`.

In other words:

```
class EnemyA : public Enemy
{
   ... 
};
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

u need to inherit from the main class
use

```
class EnemyA : public Enemy {
public:
    void loop() {
    cout << "Pew-pew\n";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with polymorphism, but rather inheritance from a virtual class.

For this to work you have to make EnemyA through EnemyC inherit from Enemy and remove the cast, like this:

```
class EnemyA: public Enemy { // fight the powers that be ?
public:
    void loop() {
        cout << "Pew-pew\n";
    }
};

// ....

enemies.push_back(new EnemyA());
```

In its current state, your array contains only pointers to the virtual class Enemy, which defines only an interface but no implementation for loop().

The cast is basically telling the compiler "let me do this, I know what I'm doing" so the compiler does not complain, but when the code tries to find a loop method to execute, it only finds an empty table of virtual methods. This is what causes the error.